# Deploying vapor on Heroku using Docker fails on $PORT

Tags: docker, heroku, vapor

I'm trying to deploy my Vapor server side app to Heroku using Docker (I know it is possible to deploy using Git, but I want to learn more about Docker).
According to Heroku, the port to use is dynamic and should be fetched from the $PORT environment variable.

So I adapted the default Docker template for Vapor to this:

```
# Start the Vapor service when the image is run, default to listening on 8080 in production environment
ENTRYPOINT ["./Run"]
CMD ["serve", "--env", "production", "--hostname", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "$PORT"]
```

However, when I push and release this to Heroku, I see the command it will execute is this:

```
web /bin/bash ./Run serve\ --env\=production\ --hostname\=0.0.0.0\ --port\=\$PORT
```

So with all kinds of escaping characters and using /bin/bash, which is not what I specified.

When I just use a hardcoded number, it looks like this:

```
web serve --env production --hostname 0.0.0.0 --port 8080
```

How do I make it so it only replaces $PORT with the port number specified by Heroku?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CMD ./Run serve --env production --hostname 0.0.0.0 --port $PORT
```

See here: https://github.com/rzeszot/cabs-swift/blob/main/Dockerfile